# Pasar stream por puntero IntPtr a VideoView

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, stream

¿Cómo puedo pasar un argumento de tipo `IntPtr` a una `VideoView` en Xamarin?

Obtengo un stream desde un grabador de vídeo usando unas librerías propias del fabricante *( Las cuales no tienen mucha documentación )* y no consigo implementar el stream a una `VideoView` como digo.

Realmente no estoy seguro de cómo lo he hecho por lo que voy a dejar el código que me funciona en C# en un proyecto de `Windows Forms` que si me funciona, y a su vez pongo la parte de lo que estoy intentando en `Xamarin`.

## Código funcional de C# `Windows Forms`:

```
//Por aquí arriba hay configuración de direcciones ip y credenciales para el objeto. 
var info = new CHCNetSDK.LPNET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO();
info.hPlayWnd = VideoBox.Handle; //Declaro por donde se va a reproducir el Stream
CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40(idConexion,ref info, null, User); //Inicia el Stream
```

`VideoBox` es `(PictureBox)`

> Codigo **NO** funcional en `Xamarin`:

## Intento 1 usando `MediaController`:

```
var mediaController = new MediaController();
info.hPlayWnd = mediaController.Handle;
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40(idConexion,ref info, null, User);
videoView.Start();
```

## Intento 2 quitando `MediaController` solo con `VideoView`

Cuando lo he intentado con el videoView la única diferencia es que he eliminado las líneas en las que se referencia `mediaController` haciendo:

```
info.hPlayWnd = videoView.Handle; 
videoView.Start();
```

## Intento 3 usando `ImageView` como si fuera `PictureBox`

```
info.hPlayWnd = imageView.Handle;
CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40(idConexion,ref info, null, User);
```

Como digo, en ningún caso me ha funcionado. No me devuelve ningún tipo de excepción, simplemente la `VideoView` se queda en negro. Puedo asegurar que el recurso al que intento conectarme funciona 100%.

**¿Alguna idea para trasladar el código de `Windows Forms` a `Android` o alguna alternativa?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He conseguido una solución para esto, como el stream se puede ver desde cualquier navegador he optado por usar WebView para poder visualizar el "stream" que en realidad, parece ser una secuencia de imágenes y denegar el zoom y movimientos del webview para que así parezca un vídeo.

Código C#:

```
var wPlayer = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
//Zoom Out para ajustar contenido a pantalla por width
wPlayer.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true; 
wPlayer.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
wPlayer.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

wPlayer.LoadUrl("http://ip:port/?params");
```

> Axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.webkit.WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
/>


</RelativeLayout>
```